# How to handle this integer data in file

Tags: python, file

I have a **fileA.txt** as :

```
000001 
0012
1122 
00192
..
```

The file is about **25kb** with some random number on every line.

I want rearrange all these numbers with **8-digits fix length** like the below output:

```
00000001
00000012
00000112
00000192
```

I tried this :

```
f = open('fileA.txt', 'r')
content = f.readlines()
nums = [ int(x.rstrip('\n')) for x in content]
print nums
f.close()
```

output:

```
[1, 12, 1122, 192]
```

I want to rearrange this numbers and even the list-compression gets hanged here for original file. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        f_line = '{:08}'.format(int(line))
        print(f_line)
```

out:

```
00000001
00000012
00001122
00000192
```

List Comprehension:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lst = ['{:08}'.format(int(line)) for line in f]
```

out:

```
['00000001', '00000012', '00001122', '00000192']
```

.

```
format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
```

> width is a decimal integer defining the **minimum field width**. If not
>   specified, then the field width will be determined by the content.
>   **Preceding the width field by a zero ('0') character** enables sign-aware
>   zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a fill character
>   of '0' with an alignment type of '='.

[format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [zfill](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill) method, to fill your numbers with '0'.

```
nums = [ x.rstrip('\n').zfill(8) for x in content]
```

Comment: Yeah thanks..but how to handle list compression there?

Answer (score 2):

Use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to do this:

```
>>> with open('nums.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         print('{:0>8}'.format(line.strip()))
... 
00000001
00000012
00001122
00000192
```

The `0` is the fill character, `>` specifies right-alignment and `8` is the width of the filled string.

Answer (score 2):

if file is too large don't load all the data together and process it. Instead read line one by one and process each line one by one.

```
with open('fileA.txt', 'r') as f:
   with open('fileB.txt', 'w') as o: # newfile to fixed
       for line in f:
           val = line.strip('\n').zfill(8)
           print val
           o.write(val + '\n')
```